# Measuring Home Water Flow

Tags: arduino

I recently purchased an Arduino Uno and I've had lots of fun tinkering with it. I'm now interested in measuring the amount of water that flows into my house through the water line.

I'm having trouble finding an appropriate device that will let me measure the flow of water from my well and capture it with my Arduino. Can you guys please recommend a specific component or some general search terms so I can start looking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not knowledgeable with arduino but I remember once seeing a [video](http://vimeo.com/user528115) with someone checking water flows w/ arduino. Here is his page http://johnny.hcssl.iat.sfu.ca/projects/h2o-ware/ . Any flow sensor/meter will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeedstudio sells a flow sensor: http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/g12-water-flow-sensor-p-635.html?cPath=144_151&zenid=2550fe072947d974a46772da306b7a46

It's probably too small for your application, but it could be a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out to me. And indeed, it looks like a very good place to start out. It appears I'll be able to easily measure water flow through a garden hose, which is, again a great place to start.

Comment: There's a range of different sized sensors at futurlec.com too.

Comment: up to 30 l/min, that's half a liter per second. Doesn't sound like small to me.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia [has a page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_meter) on different methods of measuring water flow. If you wanted to build the sensor yourself, then the [ultrasonic flow meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasonic_flow_meter) would be probably the easiest.